# Automatically set username in database.yml for Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When you generate a new rails app with postgres as db it automatically set username to appname in **database.yml**.

You then have to manually change it to your username or the app will not run.

Is there any way to automatically set it to logged in user (at time of running rails new) or other preset username?

In development and test environments it will always be the same username and production does not matter as it always deployed on heroku.

I am on ubuntu, but would be great to hear solutions for mac users also.

Comment: Are you really using `rails new` so often that this matters?

Comment: I am using it with a template to automatically add gems and run generators. Some generators will require `rake db:create` to already have run as they create migrations. It wont create the db's if the username is incorrect thus losing the usefulness of the template (works great with sqlite)

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, myself, and Meagar has a point that the effort is quite minimal. However I just stumbled upon [this](http://everydayrails.com/2010/05/22/bootstrapping-rails-template.html) which might possibly help you do what you're looking to do. *Edit: Nevermind I guess you're already using templates. Never used them myself, so can't advise beyond that. I assume there's no easy way to affect the generated database.yml*

Comment: Thanks Paul, this line in that post will do the trick `run "cp config/database.yml config/database.example"`

Comment: Ok not quite, but a step in the right direction. Will change it to copy template in from outside the app but would still need to play around to change the db names once it is copied.

Comment: You could also use SED: sed -i '' -e "s/${PWD##*/}$/$USER/g" config/database.yml (tested on mac OS x) :-)

Comment: Thanks Adam, cant get it to work as yet...starting to read documentation on SED...this could take a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I ended up doing this:
In my template I added this line to replace the username:
`gsub_file "config/database.yml", /username: .*/, "username: myusername"`
I have a simple workflow of sole developer on dev machine so usernames for developement and test will always be the same and production does not matter as it deploys to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good habit to make a new user for each application. to do this, first create `adminpack` extension as follows:

```
$ psql postgres -c 'CREATE EXTENSION "adminpack”;'
```

Open database prompt to create a new user. lets say your app called blog:

```
$ psql -d postgres
postgres=# create role blog login createdb ;
postgres=# \q
```

Now create your database and associate that to the user you just made:

```
$ createdb -E UTF8 -w -O blog blog_development
```

To check of its created:

```
$ psql -l
```

Comment: And `adminpack` was necessary because ...?